# How can I pass configuration variable values into the pyodbc connect command?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyodbc, pythoncard

I have a .ini (configuration file) where I have mentioned the server name, Database Name, UserName and Password with which I can connect my app to the MSSQL

```
self.db = pyodbc.connect(
    'driver={SQL Server};server=homeserver;database=testdb;uid=home;pwd=1234')`
```

corresponding data mentioned above connect statement is now in config.ini

```
self.configwrite = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
configread = SafeConfigParser()
configread.read('config.ini')

driver = configread.get('DataBase Settings','Driver')
server = str(configread.get('DataBase Settings','Server'))
db = str(configread.get('DataBase Settings','Database'))
user = str(configread.get('DataBase Settings','Username'))
password = str(configread.get('DataBase Settings','Password'))'
```

How can I pass these variables in the pyodbc connect statement?

I tried this:

```
self.db = pyodbc.connect('driver={Driver};server=server;database=db;uid=user;pwd=password')
```

But I am getting an error.

Comment: In order to add a variable in a string in Python you need an 'f' to precede the string. Which I guess is why they are called f-strings. ````self.db = pyodbc.connect(f'driver={driver};server={server};database={db};uid={user};pwd={password}')````

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
self.db = pyodbc.connect('driver={%s};server=%s;database=%s;uid=%s;pwd=%s' % ( driver, server, db, user, password ) )
```

%s is used to include variables into the string

the variables are placed into the string according to their order after the %

Answer (score 22):

Other options for the [connect](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/The-pyodbc-Module#connect) function:

```
# using keywords for SQL Server authentication
self.db = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, server=server, database=db,
                         user=user, password=password)

# using keywords for Windows authentication
self.db = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, server=server, database=db,
                         trusted_connection='yes')
```

Answer (score 2):

[Mixing strings and input variable in sql connection string using pyodbc library - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058650/mixing-strings-and-input-variable-in-sql-connection-string-using-pyodbc-library/57060627)
inspired of this answer

```
`conn=pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                    'Server='+servername+';'
                    'Database=master;'
                    'UID=sa;'
                    'PWD='+pasword+';'
                    )`
```