# Given a URL location of a SQL Server, create a SQL Alchemy Engine to run SQL queries from

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am working on creating a connection from a new server to a Microsoft SQL Server that hosts a database I want to access. I am struggling to figure out what is the correct connection string that I need to pass to SQL Alchemy's create_engine function.

```
driver = 'SQL Server'
**server = 'test-sql2017.xxxx.ttttttt.com'**
database = 'reporting'
user = 'username'
pw = 'password'


conn_string = f"""DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={user};PWD={pw};"""
connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": conn_string})
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)

query = 'yyyyy'
data = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
```

Specifically I am wondering how I would use the server address that is defined above to create an engine to run queries on. When I run the above code I get the following error:

> OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect);
> [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)') (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

Comment: There are some suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860620/cannot-establish-connection-to-sql-server-using-pyodbc-on-windows-7 to try

Comment: Aside... you shouldn't do this any more, `driver = 'SQL Server'`. This will usually choose the deprecated _SQL Server Native Client_ driver that hasn't had any feature updates since SQL Server 2012 and Microsoft finally stopped shipping it as of SQL Server 2022. Ideally you should be using the modern and supported ODBC drivers, e.g.: `driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'` or `driver = 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server'`, especially if you want to access new features in Azure, or in SQL Server 2014 or later.