# Parameterize pyodbc connect string using keyword arguments from my qodbc API?

Tags: python, pyodbc, qodbc

Help me to understand if I can parameterize my connection string for a [`pyodbc`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) connection to this [`qodbc`](https://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2738/0/qodbc-desktop-how-to-connect-to-qodbc-using-python) interface for QuickBooks:

`pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=qremote_dsn;IPAddress=192.168.0.50;Port=4500;RemoteDSN=login_dsn;OpenMode=F;OLE DB Services=-2;', autocommit=True)`

I have several different DSNs, RemoteDSNs and servers which I'd like to loop over. Several SO posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084969/how-can-i-pass-configuration-variable-values-into-the-pyodbc-connect-command) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505081/python-pyodbc-how-to-connect-to-a-specific-instance)) point to this [code.google documentation](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/Module.wiki#connect) suggesting I can use *strings, keywords, or both* with pyodbc's `connect` function.

pyodbc works with many different odbc APIs, so how do determine if *any* of the pyodbc keywords will map to my required qodbc keywords?

My search for the `qodbc` keywords in the [pyodbc documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki) returns no results. Must I conclude f-strings are my only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Must I conclude f-strings are my only option?

Not at all.

pyodbc is built to deal with *any* ODBC driver, so it does not identify which keywords are "legal" and which ones arent. As explained [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Module#connect) there are a few keywords that are specified by the DBAPI spec, and a few keywords reserved for pyodbc internal use, and they *"are not passed to the odbc driver"* implying that other keywords *are* passed to the ODBC driver.

Example: When I use this `connect` call ...

```py
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
    server="192.168.0.179,49242",
    database="myDb",
    uid="sa", pwd="_whatever_",
    trusted_connection="no"
)
```

... the ODBC trace shows that this is the connection string passed to the driver

```
[ODBC][2404][1589493655.363466][SQLDriverConnectW.c][290]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0xf7d9c0
            Window Hdl = (nil)
            Str In = [driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;server=192.168.0.179,49242;database=myDb;uid=sa;pwd=_whatever_;trusted_connection=no;][length = 122 (SQL_NTS)]
```

Note that `trusted_connection` is specific to SQL Server.

Comment: Hmm. I was naively going in that direction until I ran across this param: `OLE DB Services` <-- has spaces.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's a "complication". ☺️ I use SQL Server ODBC quite a lot and I've never needed to use that connection string parameter. What do you use it for? Do you need to pass different values to it each time?

Comment: Ok. So looks like I might need to experiment with string + keywords; And answering your question, details in the OP, but each connection is to a different QuickBooks company file from which I need to obtain weekly reports.

Comment: Sure, but do you ever need to use an `OLE DB Services` value other than `-2`?

Comment: Thank you for your patience helping me see how to solve this, `pyodbc.connect('OpenMode=F;OLE DB Services=-2;', [kwargs])`